# Не применяются стили CSS к ссылкам в HTML

Tags: html, css

В файле style.css есть стиль для дива themes (.themes - 67 строка) - но стиль не применяется к ссылкам.

Стиль работает если прописывать каждый раз для каждой ссылки индивидуально (17-18 строки на втором скриншоте + результат слева на странице. "About software" горит фиолетовым + подчеркивание, хотя он находится в блоке class="themes". По логике - должно работать.

Почему CSS стиль из внешнего файла не работает для ссылок в HTML - что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите пожалуйста скриншоты и вставьте минимальный код для описания проблемы. Желательно сниппетом.

Answer (score 1):

На Вашем скриншоте не указан код для цвета ссылок, только для обычного текста. Как и написал @navruz_eraliev:

```
.themes a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Должно решить Вашу проблему.

Возможно, у Вас указывается какой-то отдельный код для :visited ссылок, и он окрашивает их в другой цвет.

Answer (score 0):

```
.themes a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Да, я знаю что так можно. Но этот код не работает именно к ссылкам, увы. Приходится для каждой ссылки писать отдельно код внутри файла - не во внешнем, как предлагаете вы.